# NSOperationQueue worse performance than single thread on computation task

Tags: swift, multithreading, macos, performance

My first question!

I am doing CPU-intensive image processing on a video feed, and I wanted to use OperationQueue. However, the results are absolutely horrible. Here's an example—let's say I have a CPU intensive operation:

```
var data = [Int].init(repeating: 0, count: 1_000_000)

func run() {
  let startTime = DispatchTime.now().uptimeNanoseconds
  for i in data.indices { data[i] = data[i] &+ 1 }
  NSLog("\(DispatchTime.now().uptimeNanoseconds - startTime)")
}
```

It takes about 40ms on my laptop to execute. I time a hundred runs:

```
(1...100).forEach { i in run(i) }
```

They average about 42ms each, for about 4200ms total. I have 4 physical cores, so I try to run it on an OperationQueue:

```
var q = OperationQueue()
(1...100).forEach { i in
  q.addOperation {
    run(i)
  }
}
q.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()
```

Interesting things happen depending on q.maxConcurrentOperationCount:

```
concurrency      single operation        total
     1                 45ms             4500ms
     2              100-250ms           8000ms
     3              100-300ms           7200ms
     4              250-450ms           9000ms
     5              250-650ms           9800ms
     6              600-800ms          11300ms
```

I use the default QoS of `.background` and can see that the thread priority is default (0.5). Looking at the CPU utilization with Instruments, I see a lot of wasted cycles (the first part is running it on main thread, the second is running with OperationQueue):

[image: CPU Utilization]

I wrote a simple thread queue in C and used that from Swift and it scales linearly with the cores, so I'm able to get my 4x speed increase. But what am I doing wrong with Swift?

*Update:* I think we have concluded that this is a legitimate bug in DispatchQueue. Then the question actually is what is the correct channel to ask about issues in DispatchQueue code?

Comment: Isn't there data conflict? One thread locked due other thread doing write at the same index?

Comment: Marek, there is, but I do not care about the the result of the computation, I just needed a computation that lasts ~50ms.

Comment: Try to make run func as an NSOperation subclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to measure the wall-clock time of each `run` execution. This does not seem to be the right metric. Parallelizing the problem does not signify that each run will execute faster... it just means that you can do several runs at once.

Anyhow, let me verify your results.

Your function `run` seems to take a parameter some of the time only. Let me define a similar function for clarity:

```
func increment(_ offset : Int) {
  for i in data.indices { data[i] = data[i] &+ offset }
}
```

On my test machine, in release mode, this code takes 0.68 ns per entry or about 2.3 cycles (at 3.4 GHz) per addition. Disabling bound checking helps a bit (down to 0.5 ns per entry).

Anyhow. So next let us parallelize the problem as you seem to suggest:

```
var q = OperationQueue()
for i in 1...queues {
    q.addOperation {
      increment(i)
    }
}
q.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()
```

That does not seem particular safe but is it fast?

Well, it is faster... I hit 0.3 ns per entry.

Source code : https://github.com/lemire/Code-used-on-Daniel-Lemire-s-blog/tree/master/extra/swift/opqueue

Comment: Daniel, I only measure the elapsed time because it was weird that it would take longer per each item. When they are running on my thread queue, each operation still takes 45ms, so spawning 8 threads means I can do 8 of those at a time. With NSOperationQueue, each of the 8 starts taking 10 times longer, making the queue useless.

Comment: @neb Have you tried running the code I tested? https://github.com/lemire/Code-used-on-Daniel-Lemire-s-blog/tree/master/extra/swift/opqueue  I'd be interested in your numbers on this  test.

Comment: sorry to necro-post, I've recently run your code again. Something must have changed, because now I'm seeing linear speedup up to the number of processors. I never thanked you for taking the time to write this up and test it—thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`.background` Will run the threads with the lowest priority. If you are looking for fast execution, consider `.userInitiated` and make sure you are measuring the performance with compiler optimizations turned on.

Also consider using DispatchQueue instead of OperationQueue. It might have less overhead and better performance.

Update based on your comments: try this. It goes from 38s on my laptop to 14 or so.

Notable changes:

- I made the queue explicitly concurrent
- I run the thing in release mode
- Replaced the inner loop calculation with random number, the original got optimized out
- QoS set to higher level: QoS now works as expected and `.background` runs forever

var data = [Int].init(repeating: 0, count: 1_000_000)

```
func run() {
    let startTime = DispatchTime.now().uptimeNanoseconds
    for i in data.indices { data[i] = Int(arc4random_uniform(1000)) }
    print("\((DispatchTime.now().uptimeNanoseconds - startTime)/1_000_000)")
}

let startTime = DispatchTime.now().uptimeNanoseconds
var g = DispatchGroup()
var q = DispatchQueue(label: "myQueue", qos: .userInitiated, attributes: [.concurrent])
(1...100).forEach { i in
    q.async(group: g) {
        run()
    }
}
g.wait()
print("\((DispatchTime.now().uptimeNanoseconds - startTime)/1_000_000)")
```

Something is still wrong though - serial queue runs 3x faster even though it does not use all cores.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I should have mentioned that I've tried changing QoS parameters, but it did not make any difference in my tests, I've tried them all. DispatchQueue is a good suggestion—it does not have a primitive for a bounded thread queue, but I did try implementing a bounded queue on top of it and found that the same thing happened to the performance.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of future readers, two observations on multithreaded performance:

1. There is a modest overhead introduced by multithreading. You need to make sure that there is enough work on each thread to offset this overhead. As the old [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW23) says

   > You should make sure that your task code does a reasonable amount of work through each iteration. As with any block or function you dispatch to a queue, there is overhead to scheduling that code for execution. If each iteration of your loop performs only a small amount of work, the overhead of scheduling the code may outweigh the performance benefits you might achieve from dispatching it to a queue. If you find this is true during your testing, you can use striding to increase the amount of work performed during each loop iteration. With striding, you group together multiple iterations of your original loop into a single block and reduce the iteration count proportionately. For example, if you perform 100 iterations initially but decide to use a stride of 4, you now perform 4 loop iterations from each block and your iteration count is 25.

   And [goes on to say](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW2):

   > Although dispatch queues have very low overhead, there are still costs to scheduling each loop iteration on a thread. Therefore, you should make sure your loop code does enough work to warrant the costs. Exactly how much work you need to do is something you have to measure using the performance tools.
   >
   > A simple way to increase the amount of work in each loop iteration is to use striding. With striding, you rewrite your block code to perform more than one iteration of the original loop.
2. You should be wary of using either operations or GCD dispatches to achieve multithreaded algorithms. This can lead to “thread explosion”. You should use `DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform` (previously known as `dispatch_apply`). This is a mechanism for performing loops in parallel, while ensuring that the degree of concurrency will not exceed the capabilities of the device.